# How to use AssertThat to check the property value of objects in a list?

Tags: java, unit-testing, assert, hamcrest, assertthat

I am to using asserThat to verify properties of objects in an ArrayList.

I am able to use assertThat if none of the objects contains data to be    tested but I am not able to figure how to use assertThat if only one    of the objects contain data to be tested.

**Sample Code:**

```
public class dataNeeded {
    String data;
    String modifiedDate;

    public String getData(){
         return data;
    }
    ......
}

public ArrayList<dataNeeded> returnsNeededData(){
 ...
}

List<dataNeeded> dataToBeTested = returnsNeededData();
dataToBeTested.forEach(data->assertThat(data.getData(), not(equalTo("No"))));

List<dataNeeded> dataToBeTested2 = returnsNeededData();
// I need to verify if one of the objects in this list has it's data as "No" 
dataToBeTested.forEach(data->assertThat(data.getData(), ???);
```

Comment: Can you call the .contains() method on the list?

Comment: .contains() method on the list will check for the objects but not the properties of the objects in the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map to `List<String>` via the following function (uses Java 8 Streams) to extract all data strings

```
private List<String> mapToDataStrings(List<dataNeeded> neededData) {
    return neededData.stream()
            .map(dataNeeded -> dataNeeded.getData())
            .collect(toList());
}
```

and then use the [`everyItem`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#everyItem(org.hamcrest.Matcher))/[`hasItem`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#hasItem(T)) function in [`Matchers`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html) to make assertions on the resulting list of strings:

```
List<String> dataToBeTested = mapToDataStrings(returnsNeededData());
assertThat(dataToBeTested, everyItem(not("No")));

List<String> dataToBeTested2 = mapToDataStrings(returnsNeededData());
assertThat(dataToBeTested2, hasItem("No"));
```

With [`everyItem`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#everyItem(org.hamcrest.Matcher)) you can assert that every element in the list is not "No" and [`hasItem`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#hasItem(T)) asserts that there is at least one element in the list with value "No".

---

Alternatively you could implement a [feature matcher](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/FeatureMatcher.html) to avoid the mapping function.